# How to get hard disk information on linux terminal?

Tags: disk, system-information

We can get CPU information using `lscpu` command, is there any command to get hard disk information on Linux terminal, in a similar way?

Comment: What kind of information are you looking for? Edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 78):

If you are looking for partitioning information you can use `fdisk` or `parted`.

If you are more interested into how the various partitions are associated with the mount points try `lsblk` which I often use as:

```
lsblk -o "NAME,MAJ:MIN,RM,SIZE,RO,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID"
```

to include `UUID` info.

And finally `smartctl -a /dev/yourdrive` gives you detailed info like:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD40EFRX-68WT0N0
Serial Number:    WD-WCC4E4LA4965
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 261ca5a3f
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    4,000,787,030,016 bytes [4.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2 (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Apr  3 10:59:55 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

and more.

Some of these commands need to be run sudo to get all info.

Comment: Use gdisk for GPT partitioned diska

Comment: `smartctl` does NOT work on every storage device... specially old ones

Answer (score 32):

You can use `lshw`:

```
sudo lshw -c disk
```

But for newer kernels, i would suggest the portable and stable way of reading from `sysfs`:

```
/sys/block/sd*/device/*
```

Comment: Using sysfs is portable and stable??

Comment: @Otheus unless you are using archaic kernel..

Comment: I'm asking because I have no idea. There seems to be no requirement that `/sys` is actually mounted, and I don't recall seeing it on certain embedded flavors. I  also have no idea if it is declared "stable" by the linux kernel maintainers or if, as has been in the past, its interface might change from version to version. 

BTW: You might want to note `/sys/block/sd*` will pick up only scsi disks. You'd have to do something more clever to figure out what block devices are actually disks, and some way to distinguish virtual from physical, eliminate loop, ram, and device mapper devices

Answer (score 22):

Another one you can try in addition to what has already been suggested is:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

---

From [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/hdparm.8.html):

```
DESCRIPTION

   hdparm provides a command line interface to various kernel interfaces
   supported by the Linux SATA/PATA/SAS "libata" subsystem and the older
   IDE driver subsystem.  Many newer (2008 and later) USB drive
   enclosures now also support "SAT" (SCSI-ATA Command Translation) and
   therefore may also work with hdparm.  E.g. recent WD "Passport"
   models and recent NexStar-3 enclosures.  Some options may work
   correctly only with the latest kernels.
```

Comment: By this command you can get disk's serial number even if it is connected via adapter to USB.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the following command:

```
lshw -class disk -class storage
```

Comment: shows only controller info, not actual disk info